# Website parsing c# - Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, windows-phone, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to parse `<a href=""></a>` tag of a website. I am trying to get the href attribute value present in each of such 'description' span classes.

[image]

I tried the following code

```
HtmlNodeCollection sp = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='description']//a");
                        foreach (HtmlNode link in sp)
                        {
                            HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(att.Value);
                        }
```

I am not able to get the href attribute value. What is my mistake ?

Comment: What's not working with that code?

Comment: XPath seems fine and it should give you `href` value. What error you get?

Answer (score 2):

[image]
You can use chrome developer tools (F12), it can help you easy to get correct xPath syntax (Copy XPath)